# Why android 10 ,11 and 12 sharing specific intent in apps showing only 3 apps?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, android-pendingintent, intentfilter

I have to share content/video/image only the specified apps, I searched and tried lot but I'm not able achieve. how can able to achieve that Could you please any one help me ?

My code is below. What am I missing?

```
fun shareIntentSpecificApps() {
        val intentShareList: MutableList<Intent> = ArrayList()
        val shareIntent = Intent()
        shareIntent.action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
        shareIntent.type = "text/plain"
        val resolveInfoList = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(shareIntent, 0)
        for (resInfo in resolveInfoList) {
            val packageName = resInfo.activityInfo.packageName
            val name = resInfo.activityInfo.name
            Log.d("TAG", "Package Name : $packageName")
            Log.d("TAG", "Name : $name")
            if (packageName.contains("com.facebook") ||
                packageName.contains("com.twitter.android") ||
                packageName.contains("com.google.android.apps.plus") ||
                packageName.contains("com.google.android.gm")||
                packageName.contains("com.linkedin.android")

            ) {
                if (name.contains("com.twitter.android.DMActivity")) {
                    continue
                }
                val intent = Intent()
                intent.component = ComponentName(packageName, name)
                intent.action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
                intent.type = "text/plain"
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Your Subject")
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Your Content")
                intentShareList.add(intent)
            }
        }
        if (intentShareList.isEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "No apps to share !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        } else {
            val chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(intentShareList.removeAt(0), "Share via")
            chooserIntent.putExtra(
                Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS,
                intentShareList.toTypedArray<Parcelable>()
            )
            startActivity(chooserIntent)
        }
    }
```

Comment: It is not very clear. What are you trying to achieve, and what happens instead?
You want the share dialog that appears to only contain those 3 speciffic apps?

Comment: when tab on button sharing the content to the social media apps (Whatsup,facebook,etc )

Answer (score 1):

Starting with Android 11, there is a restriction to how apps can scan for other apps on the users device.

See [the official android statement](https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility)  and [this article](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/package-visibility-in-android-11-cc857f221cd9)

> The limited app visibility affects the return results of methods that give information about other apps, such as queryIntentActivities(), getPackageInfo(), and getInstalledApplications(). The limited visibility also affects explicit interactions with other apps, such as starting another app's service.

> Some packages are still visible automatically. Your app can always see these packages in its queries for other installed apps. To view other packages, declare your app's need for increased package visibility using the  element. The use cases page provides examples for common app interaction scenarios.

Using your code, if i added something like this to the manifes, it will show these 2 apps ( in this case facebook, and facebook messenger), but you need to know the full package name of the apps you want.

```
<queries>
    <package android:name="com.facebook.katana" />
    <package android:name="com.facebook.orca" />
</queries>
```

**However**, i don't understand the need to limit the apps the user can share to. It is much easier to just display the default share picker and let the user decide where he wants to share.